# Dictionary and radio button with c#

Tags: c#, arrays, dictionary, radio-button, radiobuttonlist

Hi so im making radio buttons that represent male and female and a separate set of radio buttons that are years: 2008 and 2010.

They are supposed to be used to get information out of dictionary and depending on the selected radio buttons; they get the respective information. Does anyone have any ideas to get the information out of the dictionary?

```
private Dictionary<Int32, String> GetLifeExpectancyDictionary(string lifeExpectancyTable)
    {
        Dictionary<Int32, String> returnArray = new Dictionary<Int32, String>();
        switch (lifeExpectancyTable)
        {
            case "MaleTable2008":
                returnArray.Add(0, "75.6");
                returnArray.Add(1, "75.1");
                break;
            case "FemaleTable2008":
                returnArray.Add(0, "80.6");
                returnArray.Add(1, "80.1");
                break;
            case "MaleTable2010":
                returnArray.Add(0, "76.2");
                returnArray.Add(1, "75.7");
                break;
            case "FemaleTable2010":
                returnArray.Add(0, "81.0");
                returnArray.Add(1, "80.5");
                break;
        }

        return returnArray;
    }
```

Comment: What are you asking for help with?

Comment: It's not clear what exactly you're asking for help with

Comment: @Dispersia how to pull the information out

Comment: What information are you trying to pull out. Also, stop breaking the formatting. A user fixed it, put his edit back.

Answer (score 1):

Dictionary is a key-value storage.
In order to get data from `Dictionary` by a `key` you should use `[key]` operator.

So, in your example

```
var dict = GetLifeExpectancyDictionary("something");
var first = dict[0];
```

If you want to get all values, you should use the `Values` property `dict.Value`.
Also probably you will want to check if a key exists in a dictionary. In order to achieve this use `ContainsKey` method.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've got it completely in reverse. Should be something like this

```
private Dictionary<string, int> _data;
// Initialize
private void InitData()
{
    _data = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    _data.Add("MaleTable2008_0", 75.6m);
    _data.Add("MaleTable2008_1", 75.1m);
    _data.Add("FemaleTable2008_0", 80.6m);
    _data.Add("FemaleTable2008_1", 80.1m);
    _data.Add("MaleTable2010_0", 76.2m);
    _data.Add("MaleTable2010_1", 75.7m);
    _data.Add("FemaleTable2010_0", 81m);
    _data.Add("FemaleTable2010_1", 80.5m);

}

private decimal GetAvgLifespan(string group)
{
    if (_data.ContainsKey(group))
        return _data[group];

    return 0m;
}
```